# Wordpress Custom Ajax Login returning entire page HTML on success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, authentication

I've created a custom ajax login as per [this tutorial](http://wpmu.org/how-to-use-ajax-with-php-on-your-wp-site-without-a-plugin/) but I'm having an issue. I'm using this jquery code to send the ajax request:

```
function ajaxLogin(form) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: loginScript.ajaxurl,
        data: "action=cb_register_login_submit&" + $(form).serialize(),
        global: false,
        success: function( msg ){
            //location.reload( true ); // This could be nicer
            handleLoginReturn(msg);
        },
        error: function(er) {
            handleErrorReturn(er);
        }
    });
}

function handleLoginReturn(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

and the following PHP function to handle the login process:

```
<?php

function cb_register_login_submit() {

    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['pwd'];

    if ( isset( $_POST['remember'] ) ) {
        $creds['remember'] = true;
    }

    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        echo 'error';
    } else {
        echo 'success';
    }
    die(0);
}

?>
```

So the problem is that when I enter the wrong login info, I do in fact get the string "error" returned through the ajax success callback but when I put in the correct log info, an entire page worth of html (which I think is the wordpress dashboard code) is returned through the success callback instead of the string "success". In fact the string "success" doesn't seem to be returned anywhere in the success callback.

Any idea what's wrong here? I am assuming that maybe the wp_signon function is returning data on success that I'm unaware of. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What I am thinking even though I don't mess with wordpress (that's a whole another tangent), is that is_wp_error() is that wordpress triggers some default code output when the wp_signon fails. Perhaps, there is a way to turn off the crazy wordpress error outputs?

Comment: @JaredDrake This can't be the case because the default code output only happens when the sign in is successful. I know it's successful because I am logged in afterward (and the password is correct). I'm hesitant to post all of the output because it's a complete page worth of html, but I am almost certain it is the wordpress dashboard html. I will double check and post the results.

Comment: Whoops lol, my bad @Hendeca... :( flip my statement around  I meant it might trigger something on success like a default login.

Comment: You have remembered to add the action? This links the call to the fucntion.

Comment: Yes, it's there:

`data: "action=cb_register_login_submit&" + $(form).serialize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

I was using the "Login Logout Redirect" plugin which seems to have been sending the redirect page html upon a successful ajax call. I deactivated the plugin and everything's working splendidly!

Comment: ahh, thanks for the pointer, in my case I shot myself in the foot with doing a redirect in my `functions.php` file via `add_action('wp_login...`